# Convert CComPtr<IShelltem2> to LPWSTR*?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, winapi, visual-c++

I'm using a variable of type CComPtr and I need to modify a LPWSTR* variable. The function I use extracts metadata about file description for executable files. I am not sure about how I should allocate memory for the LPWSTR* and how to change its value to the one of the CComPtr. lpszFileDesc must get the value of description.

```
BOOL ExeDescription(LPWSTR* lpszFileDesc, LPCWSTR filePath)
{
    CComPtr<IShellItem2> item;
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(nullptr);
    *lpszFileDesc = NULL;
    BOOL fResult = TRUE;
    hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(filePath, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        fResult = FALSE;
    } 
    else
    {
        CComPtr<WCHAR> description;
        hr = item->GetString(PKEY_FileDescription, &description);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            fResult = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {

            if (!description)
            {
                *lpszFileDesc = PathFindFileNameW(filePath);
            }
            else
            {
                 // here I want to copy the contents of description 
                 // into lpszFileDesc but I don't know how
            }
            if (!*lpszFileDesc)
            {
                fResult = FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return fResult;
}
```

Also, when I call this function how do I deallocate the memory for lpszFileDesc after calling the function?
For example if in wmain() I have:

```
LPWSTR* lpszFileDesc;
ExeDescription(LPWSTR* lpszFileDesc, LPCWSTR filePath);
```

How do I deallocate the memory if I don't need the file description after that?

Comment: `GetString` will allocate the memory and then you should call `CoTaskMemFree`

Comment: What is this? `CComPtr<WCHAR>` WCHAR is not a COM interface type and cannot be used with CComPtr

Comment: and you need declare description as `PWSTR description`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Basic Errors

> ```
> HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(nullptr);
> ...
> CoUninitialize();
> ```

COM should be initialized only once at startup of the thread, because it defines the concurrency model of the thread (amongst other things). It's not up to your function to decide how COM will be initialized for the thread. Once COM is initialized for a thread, subsequent calls to `CoInitialize[Ex]` within that thread will fail anyway. So remove this code and put it into `WinMain` or the main function of the thread where you are using COM.

> ```
> CComPtr<WCHAR> description;
> ```

Using `CComPtr` is wrong here, because `IShellItem2::GetString()` does not return an interface, but a simple C string. Such "raw" memory allocated by COM API must be freed using `CoTaskMemFree()`, which can be automated by using [`CComHeapPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomheapptr-class).

## Preferred solution - change the interface

> how do I deallocate the memory for lpszFileDesc

Do yourself a favor and use `std::wstring` instead of raw C string pointer to return a string from your function. The `std::wstring` destructor takes care of deallocation automatically. Manually managing the memory of C strings is too cumbersome and error-prone. When someone else reads your code and sees `std::wstring`, there will be no question about how the memory is managed.

I suggest to change your interface like this:

```
BOOL ExeDescription(std::wstring& fileDesc, LPCWSTR filePath);
```

... and the assignment within the function body becomes:

```
if (!description)
{
    fileDesc = PathFindFileNameW(filePath);
}
else
{
    fileDesc = description;
}
```

`CComHeapPtr<WCHAR>` has a conversion operator to `WCHAR*`, that's why the assignment to `std::wstring` simply works.

Call the function like this:

```
std::wstring fileDesc;
ExeDescription(fileDesc, filePath);
// No worries about deallocation of fileDesc!
```

## Solution using original interface

That being said, here is a solution using your original interface. You can either use the [COM allocator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/memory-allocation-in-com), as `IShellItem2::GetString()` already uses it (and there will be no copying in the common case) or use a different allocator (then you always have to copy). In both cases, the *caller* is responsible to call the right deallocation function, which you have to document (another reason why I would prefer the `std::wstring` solution).

Example of using the COM allocator:

```
BOOL ExeDescription(LPWSTR* lpszFileDesc, LPCWSTR filePath)
{
    // ... other code ...

    // GetString() uses CoTaskMemAlloc() internally
    hr = item->GetString(PKEY_FileDescription, lpszFileDesc);

    // ... other code ...

    if (! *lpszFileDesc )
    {
        LPCWSTR fileName = PathFindFileNameW(filePath);

        // Allocate buffer using the COM allocator and copy fileName to it.
        std::size_t const len = wcslen(fileName);
        *lpszFileDesc = reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(CoTaskMemAlloc(len * sizeof(WCHAR)));
        if(*lpszFileDesc)
            wcscpy_s(*lpszFileDesc, len, fileName);
    }
    // ... more code ...
}
```

Usage at the caller site:

```
LPWSTR fileDesc = nullptr;
ExeDescription(&fileDesc, filePath);
// ... use fileDesc ...
CoTaskMemFree(fileDesc);
```

Simplified usage with `CComHeapPtr`:

```
CComHeapPtr<WCHAR> fileDesc;
ExeDescription(&fileDesc, filePath);
// ... use fileDesc ...
// Deallocation happens automatically through CComHeapPtr's destructor
```

Comment: I must use LPWSTR as a return type as I'm working on a big project and this function is called multiple times to modify LPWSTR variables. In this case, how would the assignment ad conversion change?

Comment: @MilMark I've added a solution using your original interface.